# How to get last record? (JS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to get last date time like 24-02-11 (updated desc) of my question but through JavaScript. My way doesnt work, but $time or $all_users working perfectly.

```
my_controller
  $all_users                 = User.count('id')
    $last_question             = Question.find(:last, :order => "updated_at DESC", :limit => 1)
  $time                      = Time.now.strftime("%d %B, %Y")
```

my_layout_view

```
  <% javascript_tag do %>
    Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = '<%= image_path '/ext/resources/images/default/s.gif' %>';
    <%= "time = \"#{$time}\"" %>;
    <%= "last_question = \"#{$last_question}\"" %>;
  <% end %>
```

my_view

```
..........
    items : [
         {
         region      : 'north',
         minWidth    : 75,
         height      : 35,
         maxWidth    : 150,
         collapsible : false,
         resizable   : false,   
         width       : 400,
         html        : 'Last question was:' <b> + last_question + '</b>',                 
                }
.......................
```

Comment: btw, why are you using global variables?

Comment: hmm, and how else i can?

Comment: Oh, i get it :) global variable is bad to use?

Comment: What's wrong with instance variables? Sure, I don't see all your code, may be it's a forced decision.

Comment: Help me understand this, SO, global variables are using to enforce security?

Comment: In most modern languages, global variables are considered bad.  Specifically here, in your controller, there is no need for the $ in the variable names. Just go with `all_users = User.count('id')` or if it needs to be used in a view, use an instance variable: `@all_users = User.count('id')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$last_question` would return a `Question` object - not a string.  You need to get a specific value from your `Question` model and return it.

`:order => "updated_at DESC` will sort your items, but doesn't tell the `find` to only return the `updated_at` time.